# Unable to access associative array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>Home/get_officer_reporting', 
     dataType:'json',
     data: {'id':reporting_id}, //POST parameter to be sent with the tournament id
     success: function(resp) {


        console.log(resp);
   }
```

I have written an ajax request and the success of this function

the output of `console.log(resp)` is

`

```
       Array(
         [unchecked] => Array   (
                     [0] => ab1
                     [1] => ab2
                    )

          [checked] => none
       )
```

I am tryng to access `resp['unchecked']` but getting undefined on`alert(resp['unchecked'])`

Comment: in your php code instead `print_r($data)` use `echo json_encode($data)`

Comment: I did but still `alert(resp['unchecked'])`  is `undefined` http://pastebin.com/Jx2a6fFf

Comment: Only need one `dataType:'json',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use json_encode to encode response from php to json format.

```
json_encode($array);
```

Then Please try below

```
console.log(resp.unchecked);
console.log(resp.checked);
alert(resp.unchecked)
```

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use resp['unchecked'] or resp['checked'] anyways this question has been solved.. Thanks to @Pranav C Balan

Answer (score 0):

use this instead

```
json_encode($array);
```